# Recomendação e uso de tags relacionadas a Interface do Usuário

Tags: debate, tags, tags-sinônimas

Gostaria de levantar uma questão sobre as tag relacionadas a perguntas sobre interface do usuário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Particularmente tenho usado a tag UI em algumas perguntas. Mas reparei que temos outra várias tags sinônimas que poderia ser usadas. Outro ponto é que, assim como a tag UI, as outras tag relacionadas também não têm recomendações de uso nem nada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou meio em dúvida como devo usar essas tags, seria uma interface-gráfica o mesmo que uma interface-de-usuário?

Devo usar a tag UI ou a tag user-interface que não é uma abreviatura? Ou não devo usar nenhuma das duas e deveria usar termos em português, evitando tags com nomenclatura em inglês sempre que possível?

Acho que seria benéfico para a comunidade definir melhor o que é cada uma dessas tags (como é na tag Interface acima, e na tag Bootstrap abaixo), e se realmente temos a necessidade de ter todas essas tags.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>*Ainda penso se seria viável sugerir uma nova "Fila de Analise para Tags criadas", mas vou deixar esse questionamento para uma outra oportunidade...*</sub>

Comment: Eu acho que as 2 do meio são sinônimos de UI. Quem sabe a última também, e se não for será de GUI. E vocês?

Comment: Também vejo como sinônimas.

Comment: Acho que também devemos ter muito cuidado com o objetivo da tag, pois noto muita gente tendo a visão de UI (e similares) para problemas de frameworks ou kits de UI (bootstrap, ui-kit, materialdesign-css, w3c.css) sendo que ao meu ver (opinião minha) UI seria mais sobre os conceitos visuais e raramente seria necessário na maioria das perguntas (cc @Maniero)

Comment: E sobre manter os termos em Inglês vs. Português? Devemos dar preferencia por algum deles? Sobre o UI (conceito) e os Framworks tb acho que não em 90% dos casos não precisaria da tag, mas ai vão entrar pontos subjetivos, e tb acredito que não podemos "cobrar" isso dos usuários do site. Tb acho que as duas do meio são sinônimas assim como irmãs gêmeas da tag UI, mas não sei se vale a pena condensa-las em uma tag apenas...

Comment: Sei que não tenho uma alta reputação, mas na minha opinião o termo em inglês deveria ter prioridade. Ainda mais que muita coisa não tem uma boa tradução e/ou fica totalmente fora de sentido. Só de pensar em disassembly como "desmontagem" me dá ânsia (apesar de ser esta a tradução).